# jquery-confirm dialog content not updating on form change

Tags: jquery, jquery-confirm

I am currently stuck with an issue with the jquery-confirm plugin where I am unable to dynamically alter the content.

What I wish to do is basically, list all the content of the form inputs that were populated inside the content of the jquery-confirm dialog box.

However, since the initialization of the jquery-confirm occurs in the document ready event, the content only retrieves the initial status of the form inputs.

Here's the code I am using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".confirm").confirm({
            title: 'Submit the Form?',
            content: 'Form Select Value:' + $("#formSelect option:selected").text() +' <br />  Form Input Value: '+  $("#formInput").val() +' <br /> ',
            buttons: {
                formSubmit: {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    action: function () {
                        $('#myForm').submit();
                    }
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    //close
                }
            }

        }); 
});
```

The issue is that no matter what updates I make to the form input, the changes do not show inside the content of the jquery-confirm. The content always displays the initial state of the form inputs.

I have tried attaching the confirm initialization inside an on click even of the form button to try to capture the changes but it still doesn't help.

Can anyone show me how to properly bind the values of the form into the content of the jquery-confirm?

EDIT: (including a simplified version of the HTML form)

```
  <form id="myForm"  method="post" action="/processThisForm" >
      <select id="formSelect" name="formSelect" >
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="formInput" />
      <button class="confirm">Save</button>
   </form>
```

EDIT 2:

Created a jsfiddle for this code

https://jsfiddle.net/uxfb8myp/2/

Comment: can you show the related html code?

Comment: i'm not sure how that would clarify things but I included them in the edit.

Comment: If I select 2, what will be the result?

Comment: the jquery confirm dialog content would remain unchanged. as for this example, since 1 would be the initially set value. the value would remain 1 in the dialog box. and the input would value would remain blank.

Comment: added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uxfb8myp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `content` field assignment with `function` as below.

```
content: function() { 
    return 'Form Select Value:' + $("#formSelect option:selected").text() +' <br />  Form Input Value: '+  $("#formInput").val() +' <br /> '
},
```

Your complete `$(".confirm").confirm()` should be as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".confirm").confirm({
        title: 'Submit the Form?',
        content: function() { 
            return 'Form Select Value:' + $("#formSelect option:selected").text() +' <br />  Form Input Value: '+  $("#formInput").val() +' <br /> '
        },
        buttons: {
            formSubmit: {
                text: 'Submit',
                action: function () {
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                }
            },
            cancel: function () {
                //close
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hey Karan! Thanks so much! That worked! I never knew this was how to deal with updating dynamic contents from within jquery.